# Is it possible to let SPSS only display values that are significant in the Output?

Tags: output, spss, simplify

Is it possible to display only significant *P*-values and/or R-values in the output of SPSS?

This would simplify output significantly and reduces the tables to display only the relevant parts (the ones I need).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that this is a good idea, but if you want to do things such as highlight significant coefficients in a regression or blank out nonsignificant correlations in a correlation matrix, the SPSSINC MODIFY OUTPUT extension command can do this.  It is included in the Python Essentials for SPSS Statistics and can be downloaded from the SPSS Community site at www.ibm.com/developerworks/spssdevcentral or, for V21, from the same site where Statistics is kept for download or the trial site.

Answer (score 0):

I agree that there are many cases where this is not  a good idea.

In general, I find post-processing of SPSS output tables to be a little bit awkward. This is one area in which R is a lot easier to use.

For occasional analyses I often find it useful to paste an SPSS output table into Excel for further processing. For example, you could sort columns by size (e.g., mean difference, p-value, r etc.), calculate new values (e.g., mean differences, absolute correlation, etc.), make table easier to read and so on.